# DataTables not initializing properly

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am trying to use [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) to create just a basic interactive table, but can't seem to get it up and running.

My headfile

My scripts file

```
{% load static %} 
 
...
<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
   $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
  </script>
```

My Base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% include 'head.html' %}
<body>
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
<div class="page">   
{% include 'header.html' %}   

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
</div>


{% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

the table itself

```
  <table id="table_id" class="display table text-sm mb-0">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Project</th>
                          <th>Title</th>
                          <th>Description</th>
                          <th>Due Date</th>
                          <th>Priority</th>
                          <th>status</th>
                          <th>Assigned_to</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {% for ticket in tickets %}
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row">{{ ticket.id }}</th>
                          <td>{{ ticket.project }}</td>
                          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'bugtracker:ticket' ticket.id %} " role="button">{{ ticket.title }}</a></td>
                          <td>{{ ticket.description_short }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ticket.due_date }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ticket.priority }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ticket.status }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ticket.assigned_to }}</td>
                          <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'bugtracker:edit_ticket' ticket.id %}" role="button">Edit</a></td>
                          <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'bugtracker:delete_ticket' ticket.id %}" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

The head.html file:

```
{% load static %}
<head>
  ...
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.3/datatables.min.css"/>

  </head>
```

Do you see anything wrong with my set up?  I'm confused because I'm not getting any error messages.  I'm just not seeing the interactive table that should be appearing as per the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation).

Comment: You see no errors in the browser console (F11 to open)? I would expect to see something in the browser console because your table has 8 `<th>` column headings, but it has 10 body cells per row (one `<th>` element and 9 `<td>` elements). That mismatch alone looks sufficient to cause a problem for DataTables (with maybe additional issues hiding behind that).

Comment: It may help us if you include the generated HTML in the question, if the above notes do not help you.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you don't respect any of a "perfect table" ruler, datatable won't initialize.

Reading your code i've found that in  you've put 10 columns, instead of 8 columns you've put on . Try to put the same amount of columns.

These can cause the problem. In my case it works fixing these imperfections.
Let me know if it works.